# regex validation failed for following needs of mobile number

Tags: java, android, regex

I need a working regex pattern which must satisfy following conditions

1. must begin with **00 [or] +**
2. followed by one digit between **1-9**
3. followed by 11 digits between **0-9**

I have worked with following one but not working in case of

```
"^(?:00|\\+)[1-9][0-9]{11}$"
```

`00 [or] + must be followed by digit except 0` but it was not working, suggest some answer

Comment: For which input it isn't working?

Comment: 00091987654,+0987654321 it was working it must be without 0 after 00 or +

Comment: But your input doesn't have 11 digits in the end.

Comment: As per your regex it should be 11 digits after `+1`

Comment: Your regex is correct except that you have to remove one extra backslash before plus.

Comment: @guptat59 That depends on the flavor - in some cases you have to double-escape (i.e Java)

Comment: i want to have 11 or below 11 digits after +1

Comment: If you want to have maximum 11 and a minimum ..say 9 , put {9,11} or {0,11} instead of {11}

Comment: gupta59 still not working

Comment: thing is im  getting 0 after + or 00

Comment: @GowthamGS: `"^(?:00|\\+)[1-9][0-9]{0,11}$"` should work for you.

Comment: sorry friends i made some mistake in my internal calculations the above mentioned regex was working fine,thank u for ur suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:00|\+)[1-9][0-9]{11}$
```

[image]

Comment: same regex what i have mentioned above

Comment: Where did you generate this image?

Comment: sorry i made some problems with internal calculations it was working

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the default android `Pattern`:

```
android.util.Patterns.PHONE
```